# Page is showing blank in salesforce energy and utility cloud

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, energy-and-utilities

[image][image]In Salesforce Energey and Utility cloud, when I am setup the customer account after filling the forms, when I click on Confirm Move In, button, it opens up the page, where I have to fill the details and after seleting the radio button as Yes , page refresh and showing blank or if I am selecting No and clicking on No radio button and clicking on Next button, getting same experience.

Steps: Click on Account object->Open Consumer Account->click Start Service button->fill the forms( here you have to select again consumer) and continue the process and reach till confirm move in page. On this page, you have to fill the form and when you select " the account will be billed" select as Yes, then it throws an blank page or when you select No then click on Next button, it throws the same blank page.

It is purely configuration, I am using out of the box feature. Not sure, what is missing here.